# How can I get the form value for multiple uses of an id, document.getElementById('example').value

Tags: javascript, firebase, jquery-selectors

I have a form that is having values stored in firebase. I have multiple instances of "size" and am trying to get a single value reported. I have tried querySelectorAll(), getElementById(), and querySelector(). I am new to javascript so I am struggling to get this working.

Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<div id="flap-2"><label for="size">Size <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select id="size" name="size">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="example1A">example option 1 A</option>
    <option value="example2A">example option 2 A</option>
    <option value="example3A">example option 3 A</option>
    <option value="example4A">example option 4 A</option>
    <option value="example5A">example option 5 A</option>
    <option value="example6A">example option 6 A</option>
    <option value="example7A">example option 7 A</option>
    <option value="example8A">example option 8 A</option>
  </select> 
  </div>

  
  <div id="doors-2"><label for="size">Size <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select id="size" name="size">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="example1B">example option 1 B</option>
    <option value="example2B">example option 2 B</option>
    <option value="example3B">example option 3 B</option>
    <option value="example4B">example option 4 B</option>
    <option value="example5B">example option 5 B</option>
    <option value="example6B">example option 6 B</option>
    <option value="example7B">example option 7 B</option>
    <option value="example8B">example option 8 B</option>
  </select> 
  </div>

  <div id="plex-2"><label for="size">Size <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select id="size" name="size">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="example1C">example option 1 C</option>
    <option value="example2C">example option 2 C</option>
    <option value="example3C">example option 3 C</option>
    <option value="example4C">example option 4 C</option>
    <option value="example5C">example option 5 C</option>
    <option value="example6C">example option 6 C</option>
    <option value="example7C">example option 7 C</option>
    <option value="example8C">example option 8 C</option>
  </select> 
  </div>
```

And here is the JS I am using:

```
const width = document.getElementById('width').value;
const height = document.getElementById('height').value;
const thickness = document.querySelector('input[name="thickness"]:checked').value;
const orientation = document.querySelector('input[name="orientation"]:checked').value;
const brand = document.getElementById('brand').value;
const size = document.getElementById('size').value;
const extrusion = document.querySelector('input[name="extrusion"]:checked').value;
const series = document.querySelector('input[name="series"]:checked').value;



db.doc().set({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    thickness: thickness,
    orientation: orientation,
    brand: brand,
    size: size,
    extrusion: extrusion,
    series: series

}).then( () => {
    console.log('Data Saved')
    alert("success")
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

})

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: +1 to the above. You need to rewrite your HTML. You probably want to use a class rather than an ID if you want to be able to fetch multiple elements.

Comment: I add class to each of the size fields and receive "Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined" when submitting the form.